# IE7: Extra space caused by Clearfix container with element `float: right;` and margin

Tags: css, html, internet-explorer, internet-explorer-7

I am experiencing a weird bug in IE7 where margin is seemingly added twice. Once in the normal spot below the `thing` element and another between the button and bottom of the container. *Note, there is `margin-bottom` on the button itself but I am talking about the extra margin added below that.*

You can see in the gif below, that when I toggle the `margin-bottom` on the `thing` element, it toggles space between the `thing` element and the button(normal) but also between the button and the end of the container(bug).

I have a feeling that this is part of the `zoom: 1;` hasLayout clearfix used on the `.block`. If I add an explicit `clear: both;` div, it also has this extra space but that can be mitigated with putting `height: 0;` on the clear div.

**This extra space only appears with `float: right;` on the button**

I am using a HTML5 doctype but have also tried a strict doctype and it has no effect in the true IE7 or emulated version.

How can I remove the extra space at the bottom while maintaining the self clearing [micro-clearfix](http://nicolasgallagher.com/micro-clearfix-hack/) dom structure?

The gif below is from Windows 8.1 IE with IE7 emulation/compatibility. Here is the [same bug in true IE7 on Windows XP](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yLa6a.png).

[image]

### Code:

```css
.block
{
    background: #888888;
    
    /* Clearfix */
    zoom: 1;
}

.thing-with-margin
{
    margin-bottom: 10px;
    
    background: #88dd88;
}

.button
{
    float: right;
    
    /* Make the input/button shrink to the correct size in ie7 */
    overflow: visible;
    
    margin-bottom: 10px;
    padding: 0 8px;
    
    background: #6666cc;
    border: 0;
}


.heading
{
    background: #aaaaaa;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #000000;
}
```

```html
This is IE7 only code at the moment stripped down to show off this problem. View it in IE7 mode.
<br />

<div class="block">
    <div class="heading">Aenean vulputate</div>
    
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet
    
    <div class="thing-with-margin">
        Ipsum dolor amet Lorem.
    </div>
    
    <input type="submit" class="button" value="Sign Up">
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have not found an explanation or someone else encountering this same issue.

But I have found a solution that works great and unfortunately is a little bit hacky.

Add this zoom declaration side by side the `zoom: 1;` on the `.block` parent element. The `expression`(*dynamic property*) value works IE7- and allows for basic JavaScript.

`zoom: expression(this.runtimeStyle.zoom="1", this.appendChild(document.createElement("br")).style.cssText="clear:both;font:0/0 serif");`

**Source:** NBFC Overflow hack in [*Better float containment in IE using CSS expressions*](http://nicolasgallagher.com/better-float-containment-in-ie/)

---

### Full Clearfix:

I suggest you use conditional stylesheets rather than CSS property hacks(`*`) but I have left them in so it is nice and copy-pasteable.

```
.clearfix
{
    /* Clearfix: http://nicolasgallagher.com/better-float-containment-in-ie/ */
    /* for IE 6/7 */
    *zoom: expression(this.runtimeStyle.zoom="1", this.appendChild(document.createElement("br")).style.cssText="clear:both;font:0/0 serif");
    /* non-JS fallback */
    *zoom: 1;
}

.clearfix:before,
.clearfix:after
{
    content: ' ';
    display: table;
}

.clearfix:after
{
    clear: both;
}
```

```css
.block
{
  background: #888888;

  /* Clearfix: http://nicolasgallagher.com/better-float-containment-in-ie/ */
  /* for IE 6/7 */
  *zoom: expression(this.runtimeStyle.zoom="1", this.appendChild(document.createElement("br")).style.cssText="clear:both;font:0/0 serif");
  /* non-JS fallback */
  *zoom: 1;
}
.block:before,
.block:after
{
  content: ' ';
  display: table;
}
.block:after
{
  clear: both;
}

.thing-with-margin
{
  margin-bottom: 10px;

  background: #88dd88;
}

.button
{
  float: right;

  /* Make the input/button shrink to the correct size in ie7 */
  overflow: visible;

  margin-bottom: 10px;
  padding: 0 8px;

  background: #6666cc;
  border: 0;
}


.heading
{
  background: #aaaaaa;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #000000;
}
```

```html
<div class="block">
  <div class="heading">Aenean vulputate</div>

  <div>
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet
  </div>

  <div class="thing-with-margin">
    Ipsum dolor amet Lorem.
  </div>

  <input type="submit" class="button" value="Sign Up">
</div>
```